# R base graphics legend doesn't consider the order in a factor

Tags: r

I'm plotting a simple graphic, it's legend is an ordered factor, but the legend appears unordered.

```
legTxt <- factor(c(1,4,3,2), levels=c(4, 3, 2, 1), labels=c("High", "Medium", "Low", "Lower"))

plot(1,1)
legend("topleft",
       legend=legTxt)
```

- Is this normal behavior of the legend function?
- Is there any function to extract the ordered text from a factor?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you want `levels()`. Try, for instance, `legend("topleft", legend = levels(legTxt))`.

Comment: Omg, silly me, I was discarding levels because it just gives me the unique values of the factor... but that's exactly what I was looking for initially. Thanks.

Comment: You bet. Glad that did the trick!

Comment: Please post an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want `levels()`. Try, for instance:

```
plot(1,1)
legend("topleft", legend = levels(legTxt))
```